# Modify Wordpress SQL Query to pull from within a category

Tags: categories, query-posts, sql

I am using a wordpress plugin called "kf most read" which stores a count of how many times a post was read, and lets you output a list of most read posts.

This works well. The issue is, I am trying to pull the most read posts, but only the most read posts within the current category you are viewing.

I am close to clueless when it comes to sql.

Here us what the plugin is currently using to pull the most read posts:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(mr.post_ID) AS totHits, p.ID, p.post_title FROM $wpdb->posts p 
JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}kf_most_read mr ON mr.post_ID = p.ID WHERE mr.hit_ts >= '".(time() - ( 86400 * $period))."'
GROUP BY mr.post_ID ORDER BY totHits DESC, ID ASC LIMIT $limit";
```

How could I incorporate the below query which pulls from a specific category into the above?

```
$sql .= "LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)";
$sql .= "WHERE $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN ($currentcat)";
$sql .= "AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'" ;
```

Any Help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the $currentcat variable is set before this query runs.  This should be the id of the category you want to pull top posts from.

```
$sql = "SELECT count(mr.post_ID) AS totHits, p.ID, p.post_title FROM $wpdb->posts p 
JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}kf_most_read mr ON mr.post_ID = p.ID 
JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE mr.hit_ts >= '".(time() - ( 86400 * $period))."' 
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN ($currentcat)
GROUP BY mr.post_ID ORDER BY totHits DESC, ID ASC LIMIT $limit";
```

Comment: As much as I hate the idea of including direct SQL queries in a plug-in (use the `WP_Query` object!!!), this is the right answer.

Comment: @EAMann I agree, try to use the query_vars object first. If that doesn't give you all you need, inject your custom SQL through filters.